# How to run a jar file with a specific icon using apple script / shell script

Tags: macos, shell, jar, applescript

I have a Java application developed for Mac. I am bundling it into a cocoa application. To start the application i am using Shell Script inside Apple script and making a call to my jar.

```
Java -jar -XstartOnFirstThread -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 Myapp.jar
```

Doing this launches the app with an executable icon. I want to replace this with my custom icon.

Comment: This appears to solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006173/how-do-you-change-the-dock-icon-of-a-java-program/15663741, or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054704/how-to-change-jar-icon-on-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Java -jar -XstartOnFirstThread -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 Myapp.jar -Xdock:icon="Path To Icon"
```

This changes the icon that appears in the Dock.