# Wrapping an executable jar file with an icon

Tags: java, jar, icons, wrapper

Background: I created a simple GUI in java and can run that GUI by clicking its executable jar file. I created the GUI in java so that it could be ran on more than one OS.

Question: Is there a way to make some sort of "wrapper icon" for the jar file so that when I click it (the icon) the GUI opens up?

To be clear I am not talking about changing the .jar file icon, that is determined by the OS. I successfully converted the jar file to a .exe, .app and .sh file with the intent of running a cmd file that would determine the OS and run the appropriate file.  But then I started feeling like I was backtracking. I know I am being picky but I just thought I would be useful for my Java programs to have different icons. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the icon of a .JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938344/changing-the-icon-of-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I created a simple GUI .. Is there a way to make some sort of "wrapper icon" for the.. (GUI)

Sure.  Launch the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It can install desktop icons and menu shortcuts with icons on supported platforms.  For further branding, add a splash.

Comment: This looks like my best option. I attempted this earlier but couldn't get it to work.  I thought maybe it had something to do with me using NetBeans GUI Builder.  More specifically the "lib" folder inside "dist" that is generated when you select build.  Should I set the application's properties to Run Web Start before I write any code?

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or simply a helpful suggestion that suggests doing things in a significantly different way than what the question itself specifies?

Comment: @MiltiadisKokkonidis  I'm not sure exactly how you'd classify it, but given the replies to [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) it is an answer well within the scope of SO.  Of course, JWS can achieve a lot besides just organizing shortcuts (see the tag Wiki linked above), but that is a topic for ..other questions.

Comment: :-) Questions that can be answered directly, but for which it is obvious that taking a different path altogether is a better option are common in SO.  Usually I try to include both components in my answers, as I think this is the most beneficial approach for the OP. Outside SO, I would probably go straight to the suggestion.  But for some reason, I tend to prefer direct answers to questions in SO.  Maybe its my Wikipedia mentality which I apparently have carried over, or maybe I am just too young in SO days and this will change with time :-) Thanks for the reply and for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Windows:  Launch4J creates an EXE from you JAR and lets you choose its icon. If you want to keep whatever tool you are currently using for building the EXE and then go and change the icon of that EXE, try Resource Hacker:
http://download.cnet.com/Resource-Hacker/3000-2352_4-10178587.html

Mac:
For changing the Mac app bundle icon, add the following in your info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>maciconfile</string>
```

having put a maciconfile.icns file in your Resources directory.

Xcode Developer Tools which you can get for free if you own a Mac have the tools you need.  If you do not have a Mac, there are tools on other platfroms that allow you to build bundles for Mac (such as the OS X Application Bundle Plugin for Maven).